# $\text{Find X such that $AX$}= \left[ \begin{array}{} 2&-1\\ 1& 0\\ 0&-3 \end{array} \right] $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\text{Assume that you are given $A^T$}= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  1&2&1\\
  3&5&3
\end{array}
\right] $$

$$\text{Find X such that  $AX$}= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  2&-1\\
  1& 0\\
  0&-3
\end{array}
\right] $$

can someone explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: If $AX = B$, then the $i$th column $x_i$ of $X$ and $b_i$ of $B$ satisfy $Ax_i = b_i$.  We can solve this linear equation to get $x_i$ for $i = 1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have matrix $A^T$, so it is easy to find matrix $A$, i.e. we know:
$$A= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  1&3\\
  2&5\\
  1&3
\end{array}
\right].$$

Now, we know type of matrix $A$ is $3×2$, and type of matrix $B$ is also $3×2$, so type of matrix $X$ must be $2×2$. In other words, we will assume:
$$X= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  x_{11}&x_{12}\\
  x_{21}&x_{22}
\end{array}
\right].$$

Next, we will have:
$$AX= \left[
\begin{array}{}
  x_{11}+3x_{21}&x_{12}+3x_{22}\\
  2x_{11}+5x_{21}&2x_{12}+5x_{22}\\
  x_{11}+3x_{21}&x_{12}+3x_{22}
\end{array}
\right].$$

Finally, because it holds $AX=B$, we have:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{}
  x_{11}+3x_{21}&x_{12}+3x_{22}\\
  2x_{11}+5x_{21}&2x_{12}+5x_{22}\\
  x_{11}+3x_{21}&x_{12}+3x_{22}
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{}
  2&-1\\
  1&0\\
  0&-3
\end{array}
\right],$$

and can easily conclude that this system of linear equation does not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$A^TA$ is invertible, hence $$X=(A^TA)^{-1}B$$

with $B=A^T(AX)$ and both $A^T$ and $AX$ are given.

Comment: How do you reconcile this with the fact that neither column of the given $AX$ lies in the column space of $A$, so there is in fact no such matrix $X$?